# Bokeh DeprecationWarning: Setting a fixed font size value as a string 'text_font_size' is deprecated

Tags: python, bokeh

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bokeh/properties.py:363:
>   DeprecationWarning: Setting a fixed font size value as a string
>   'text_font_size' is deprecated, set with value('text_font_size') or
>   ['text_font_size'] instead   super(HasProps, self).**setattr**(name,
>   value)

I am getting this warning when running this code:

```
myfig.text(x=[i], y=[.5], text=["abc"], text_align='center', text_font_size=['10pt'], text_color='#CDEFCC')
```

Can you help ? How do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that is an active bug with Bokeh. There is a [GitHub issue about it](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2524). Here is a snippet of the response:

> Hi @marcomayer looks like you found a little bug. The "list" syntax may go away anyway. You can set values like this, however:
>
> `from bokeh.properties import value`
> `p.axis.major_label_text_font_size=value("8pt")`
>
> For a little context, the reason for the deprecation is that string values for data specs are, in every other context, interpreted as column data source column names. This changes brings consistency to the interface.

Comment: Thanks, how would I fix my code above so that its stays portable after the upgrade?

I tried `myfig.text(x=[i], y=[.5], text=["abc"], text_align='center', text_font_size=value('10pt'), text_color='#CDEFCC')`
But got same error.

Comment: I'm not sure. Your follow-up question is probably better suited for the Bokeh GitHub issues page as it's a support-related question.